# How to redirect user if they have a cookie javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect, cookies

I need to know how to give the user a cookie when they visit the page for the first time in javascript. Then i need the cookie to expire in 1 hour and it to redirect them if the cookie still exists and they try to access the page before 1 hour is up.

Comment: So what's your problem in doing that?

Comment: Then don't use JS, but your favourite serverside language for that

Answer (score 0):

A related solution is described in [redirecting to a splash page](http://css-tricks.com/redirecting-to-a-splash-page-but-only-once-with-cookies/).

Answer (score 0):

if it is ok to use Jquery you can use the Jquery plugin

Set a cookie

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { path: '/', expires: 7 });
```

Get a cookie

```
alert( $.cookie("example") );
```

Delete the cookie

```
$.cookie("example", null);
```

Using this you write your custom logic for redirection in javascript