# How to redirect the user if a certain cookie exists

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to redirect user if they have a cookie javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468535/how-to-redirect-user-if-they-have-a-cookie-javascript)

Im creating a web app that gives you a random chance to win a itunes card every day. I have the layout done I just need to make it so the user cant do it more then once a day. I know cookies arnt very secure and they could just clear their cookies but I still want to use them so if somebody could please give me the code that creates a cookie that expires in one day, and some more javascript code that checks if the cookie exists and redirects them if it does, this would be greatly appreciated (Im a noob at javascript).

Comment: Please don't ask us to write your code for you. Stack Overflow exists to solve problems, not create code.

Comment: First of all, cookies are not a great idea. Do you not have a user login system? That will make it much easier to track who claimed what. As for your question, a few "googles" for how to set and read cookies and you will be on track in no time. Nobody here is going to write your code for you

Comment: Also, please don't repost your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468535

Comment: Improve existing questions with your progress and they will be automatically bumped up to the top of the Newest list, so the answers and comments from the previous one aren't lost.

Answer (score 0):

if it is ok to use Jquery you can use the Jquery plugin

Set a cookie

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { path: '/', expires: 1 });
```

Get a cookie

```
alert( $.cookie("example") );
```

Delete the cookie

```
$.cookie("example", null);
```

This should start you going in the right direction.